# Create MySQL database from .mdf and .ldf files from SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-migration

I have some .mdf and .ldf files of database size greater than 10 GB with me.

I want to create a MySQL database using the same.

Is there any provision in MySQL to do it?

Please consider that MySQL and SQL Server 2008 can not be installed on the same machine (or even the same network) in my current setup.

I don't have enterprise edition of SQL Server management studio in our network and will not be able to install it.

Is there any other elegant way to export data from SQL Server 2008 and import it in MySQL?

Comment: You can refer below links :-

1)  http://www.convert-in.com/mss2sql.htm
2)  https://dbconvert.com/mssql/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible without attaching.

If you find a way how to attach it, you can use some specific migrating tools like [this](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server-to-mysql).

Some tools allow to create database specific queries from another solution, that need to be only executed on your side.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express Edition doesn't allow attaching databases beyond 10 GB! :(

Answer (score 0):

The MDF and LDF files belong to Microsoft SQL Server and use Microsoft's own binary format, so you cannot connect these files to other database management systems. The only approach I can think of, is to script out the database code and data from the SQL Server database to a text file (.sql file), and import this file into MySQL.